# Alternative way to do something

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I published the still not finished website just to show you what I want

In this website:
http://urbanphenomena.net/shukri/#page3

the iFrame is redirecting to different images in different pages when the user clicks a specific link. Here is the code if needed:

```html
<!--- Projects Section --->
    <div class="section projects-section container-fluid" id="section4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 pull-left">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Architecture</a>
              </h4>
              <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <!--- FAF --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
                      <h5>FAF</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/1.html')">A01-FAF-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/2.html')">A01-FAF-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/3.html')">A01-FAF-3</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/4.html')">A01-FAF-4</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/5.html')">A01-FAF-5</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- KSAF --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
                      <h5>KSAF</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A02-KSAF/1.html')">A02-KSAF-1</button><br>
                    
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A02-KSAF/2.html')">A02-KSAF-2</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- KSAF10V --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
                      <h5>KSAF10V</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A03-KSAF10V/1.html')">A03-KSAF10V-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A03-KSAF10V/2.html')">A03-KSAF10V-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A03-KSAF10V/3.html')">A03-KSAF10V-3</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A03-KSAF10V/4.html')">A03-KSAF10V-4</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- Makkah --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFour">
                      <h5>Makkah</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A04-Makkah/1.html')">A03-Makkah-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A04-Makkah/2.html')">A03-Makkah-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A04-Makkah/3.html')">A03-Makkah-3</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- Marina --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFive">
                      <h5>Marina</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A05-Marina/1.html')">A05-Marina-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A05-Marina/2.html')">A05-Marina-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A05-Marina/3.html')">A05-Marina-3</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- Residential --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSix">
                      <h5>Residential</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseSix" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/1.html')">A06-Residential-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/2.html')">A06-Residential-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/3.html')">A06-Residential-3</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/4.html')">A06-Residential-4</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/5.html')">A06-Residential-5</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/6.html')">A06-Residential-6</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/7.html')">A06-Residential-7</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/8.html')">A06-Residential-8</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/9.html')">A06-Residential-9</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/10.html')">A06-Residential-10</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- SAB4 --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSeven">
                      <h5>SAB4</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseSeven" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      buttona type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A07-SAB4/1.html')">A07-SAB4-1</button><br>
                      
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A07-SAB4/2.html')">A07-SAB4-2</button><br>
                      
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A07-SAB4/3.html')">A07-SAB4-3</button><br>
                      
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A07-SAB4/4.html')">A07-SAB4-4</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
              <h4>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Interior</a>
              </h4>
              <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div id="collapse2" class="collapse in" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/1.html')">I01-Interior-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/2.html')">I01-Interior-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/3.html')">I01-Interior-3</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/4.html')">I01-Interior-4</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/5.html')">I01-Interior-5</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/6.html')">I01-Interior-6</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/7.html')">I01-Interior-7</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- SFS --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOneInt">
                      <h5>SFS</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseOneInt" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I02-SFS/1.html')">I02-SFS-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I02-SFS/2.html')">I02-SFS-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I02-SFS/3.html')">I02-SFS-3</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I02-SFS/4.html')">I02-SFS-4</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
              <h4>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Fabrication</a>
              </h4>
              <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div id="collapse3">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/1.html')">F01-Fabrication-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/2.html')">F01-Fabrication-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/3.html')">F01-Fabrication-3</button><br>
                        
                      <a type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/4.html')">F01-Fbuttonbrication-4</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/5.html')">F01-Fabrication-5</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--- iFrame --->
        <div class="col-lg-7
          col-md-7
          col-sm-12
          col-xs-12 pull-right
          col-lg-pull-3 img-container
          col-md-pull-3">
          <iframe id="iframe" src="imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/1.html" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <script>
          function setURL(url) {
            document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
          }
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is there an more accurate way to do this than iframe?

and the thing I need help with mostly is:
When I reload the page, I want one of the buttons to be highlighted after the reload.

Like the class `.active` in bootstrap, when you first reload the page, the `<li>` is already highlighted without clicking it, thats what I want for the first button which is "A01-FAF-1". But the class `active` doesn't work.

How to do it?

Comment: Why are you using an `iframe` instead of an `img` in the first place?

Comment: I suggest you look at jquery. To do what you are suggesting is very simple (I believe) in a few jquery statements. Essentially, you can pull data (image/html) from another source and populate any DIV or content-ready tag with the resulting pull. Do you have experience in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function showHer(){
        $("#TestDiv").html("Something");
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="TestDiv" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black">
Changeable stuff here.
</div>
<div onclick="showHer()" style="background:silver;border:1px solid black;cursor:pointer;display:inline;">
click me
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see, in one line, I was able to change the content of a DIV elsewhere on the page.

Also note that there are no buttons.   You can do this with a button, image, link, pretty much anything.

One other thing to note is that since you're using jquery to replace content in one small area of the page, the entire page doesn't need to update (faster) and hitting BACK doesn't just go back to the previous image, it would go back to the previous page.