# Highlight <a> when the screen load/reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this website: http://urbanphenomena.net/shukri/#page3

The `A01-FAF-01` under Architecture > FAF is a link, I want this to be highlighted when the page load/reload.

Just like the effect on the input

```
<input type="checkbox" checked/>
```

the "checked" attribute makes the check box checked on default. I want this to be the same with the A01-FAF-01 link, but highlighted....when the user clicks another Link...the highlight disappears.

Code:

```css
/* Fonts */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi.css);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700);

/******************************* CSS Reset ************************************/

html, body, div, applet, object, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr,
acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small,
strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label,
legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: "";
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: "" "";
}

/******************************************************************************/

nav {
  text-align: left;
  background-blend-mode: saturation;
}

/* li & a customization */
a[title] {
  color: #e4002b;
  font-size: 13px;
}


a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e4002b !important;
}

/* ul menu */
.nav> li {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans';
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.nav> li> a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 2px;
}


/* Website title */
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-top> div, section> div {
  height: 0;
}

.navbar h5, .navbar h6 {
  color: #b1b1b0;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans';
  padding-bottom: 6.5px;
}

#droid h5, #droid h6 {
  font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi'
}

.navbar h5 {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.navbar h6 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.gutter-20.row {
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.gutter-20> [class^="col-"], .gutter-10> [class^=" col-"] {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

/* Sliders & Pages Costumization */
.home-section img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* circle customization */
.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  -moz-border-radius: 90%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90%;
  border-radius: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: -50px;
}

/* Text inside the circle */
.text {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 20%;
}

.big, .sub-big {
  color: #F5C52C;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans';
}

.top-text, .saudi {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans';
  color: white;
}

.top-text {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 11px;
  left: -7px;
}

.big {
  font-size: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 30px;
}

.sub-big {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  left: -20px;
}

.saudi {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 13px;
  top: 115px;
  left: 29px;
}

/* About Page */
#section2 {
  color: #b1b1b0;
  background-image: url(../imgs/about-background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

#section2.background--dark {
  color: red;
}

/* Black Overlay */
.overlay {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
  left: 35%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

#section2 p, #section2 h3, #section2 h5 {
  text-align: right;
}

/* Projects Page */
#section4 {
  background-image: url(../imgs/projects-background.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#section4 h3 {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 97%;
  height: 40%;
}

.panel {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: right;
}

.panel-group h4 a {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.panel-group a {
  color: #b1b1b0;
  font-size: 11px;
}


.panel-group a:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel-group h4:hover {
  color: white;
}

/* contact Page */
.contact-section span {
  color: #e4002b;
}

.contact-section a {
  color: black;
}

.contact-section a:Hover {
  color: white;
}

.map-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.map-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
}

ol button:focus {
    background-color: #b1b1b0;
    color: #e4002b;
}

ol button {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    color: #b1b1b0;
}

/* Other */
.home-section, .about-section, .projects-section, .contact-section {
  padding-top: 95px;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans';
}
```

```html
 <!--- Projects Section --->
    <div class="section projects-section container-fluid" id="section4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 pull-left">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Architecture</a>
              </h4>
              <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <!--- FAF --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
                      <h5>FAF</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/1.html')">A01-FAF-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/2.html')">A01-FAF-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/3.html')">A01-FAF-3</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/4.html')">A01-FAF-4</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/5.html')">A01-FAF-5</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- KSAF --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
                      <h5>KSAF</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A02-KSAF/1.html')">A02-KSAF-1</button><br>
                    
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A02-KSAF/2.html')">A02-KSAF-2</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- KSAF10V --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
                      <h5>KSAF10V</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A03-KSAF10V/1.html')">A03-KSAF10V-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A03-KSAF10V/2.html')">A03-KSAF10V-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A03-KSAF10V/3.html')">A03-KSAF10V-3</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A03-KSAF10V/4.html')">A03-KSAF10V-4</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- Makkah --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFour">
                      <h5>Makkah</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A04-Makkah/1.html')">A03-Makkah-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A04-Makkah/2.html')">A03-Makkah-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A04-Makkah/3.html')">A03-Makkah-3</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- Marina --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFive">
                      <h5>Marina</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A05-Marina/1.html')">A05-Marina-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A05-Marina/2.html')">A05-Marina-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A05-Marina/3.html')">A05-Marina-3</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- Residential --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSix">
                      <h5>Residential</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseSix" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/1.html')">A06-Residential-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/2.html')">A06-Residential-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/3.html')">A06-Residential-3</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/4.html')">A06-Residential-4</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/5.html')">A06-Residential-5</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/6.html')">A06-Residential-6</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/7.html')">A06-Residential-7</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/8.html')">A06-Residential-8</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/9.html')">A06-Residential-9</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A06-Residential/10.html')">A06-Residential-10</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- SAB4 --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSeven">
                      <h5>SAB4</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseSeven" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A07-SAB4/1.html')">A07-SAB4-1</button><br>
                      
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A07-SAB4/2.html')">A07-SAB4-2</button><br>
                      
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A07-SAB4/3.html')">A07-SAB4-3</button><br>
                      
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A07-SAB4/4.html')">A07-SAB4-4</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
              <h4>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Interior</a>
              </h4>
              <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div id="collapse2" class="collapse in" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/1.html')">I01-Interior-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/2.html')">I01-Interior-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/3.html')">I01-Interior-3</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/4.html')">I01-Interior-4</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/5.html')">I01-Interior-5</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/6.html')">I01-Interior-6</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I01-Interior/7.html')">I01-Interior-7</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                  <!--- SFS --->
                  <div>
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOneInt">
                      <h5>SFS</h5>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseOneInt" class="collapse">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I02-SFS/1.html')">I02-SFS-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I02-SFS/2.html')">I02-SFS-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I02-SFS/3.html')">I02-SFS-3</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/INT/I02-SFS/4.html')">I02-SFS-4</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
              <h4>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Fabrication</a>
              </h4>
              <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div id="collapse3">
                    <ol>
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/1.html')">F01-Fabrication-1</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/2.html')">F01-Fabrication-2</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/3.html')">F01-Fabrication-3</button><br>
                        
                      <a type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/4.html')">F01-Fbuttonbrication-4</button><br>
                        
                      <button type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/5.html')">F01-Fabrication-5</button><br>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--- iFrame --->
        <div class="col-lg-7
          col-md-7
          col-sm-12
          col-xs-12 pull-right
          col-lg-pull-3 img-container
          col-md-pull-3">
          <iframe id="iframe" src="imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/1.html" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <script>
          function setURL(url) {
            document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
          }
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can also display image using base 64 encoder on page

Comment: Assign it an active css class and style it. then have jQuery toggle the class when another link is pressed. (I checked the site it does not seem to highlight anything after the click)

Comment: @CyberGeek.exe Yeah it doesn't but I did that on the local one. May you please give me a small example of your explanation, I am a starter in jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative way to do something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938398/alternative-way-to-do-something)

Comment: Here is the documentation for .click() (https://api.jquery.com/click/) For examples sake you can try $('a').click(function(){ $('active').toggleClass('active'); $(this).toggleClass('active') })

Comment: Okay, I will read this...thank you sir :)